# Validity of $C_p-C_v = R$

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

This might be a very novice question but i got confused over derivation of $C_p-C_v = R$ which is derived using $dQ= n C_p dT,$ which is valid only for isobaric process. Thus $C_p-C_v = R$ must also only be valid for isobaric process only?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice and short derivation of the wanted relation, that does not use $dQ=nC_p
dT$.

You start with specific enthalpy:

$$h=u+pv$$

substitute $$pv=RT$$ which holds for $m=1$ of the ideal gas.

And get:

$$h=u+RT$$ than you differentiate both sides with respect to $T$.

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}+R$$

and we define $$c_p :=\frac{\partial h}{\partial T} $$

and
$$c_v:=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}.$$

And get:

$$c_p=c_v+R$$

where $R$ is the specific gas constant.

So you see, the Mayer's relation hold for any process when considering the ideal gas model.